# How can an existing protocol implemented by a delegate be extended with a var?

Tags: swift

I've tried many combinations and the problem still remains. I can't figure out why Swift won't compile the following code. I've used multiple variations (using 'where' to constraint protocol, moving setter & getter inside the protocol, etc...) Still no luck. Can you see where the problem is?

```
    // GameScene.swift

    import SpriteKit

    extension SKSceneDelegate { // adding 'where Self: Game' 
// causes err to moves somewhere else
        var playerDirection: PlayerDirection { get set } // doesn't like this!
    }

    class GameScene: SKScene {
        override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
            switch (theEvent.keyCode) {
            case 123:
                delegate!.playerDirection = .Left;
            case 124:
                delegate!.playerDirection = .Right;
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }


    // SomeGame.swift

    import Foundation
    import SpriteKit

    class Game: NSObject, SKSceneDelegate {        
        var _playerDirection: PlayerDirection = .None

// moving that code to the protocol, compiler can't find _playerDirection
        var playerDirection: PlayerDirection { 
            set {
                _playerDirection = newValue
            }
            get {
                return _playerDirection
            }
        }

        lazy var scene: GameScene = {
            let scene = GameScene(size: CGSizeMake(CGFloat(100), CGFloat(100)))
            scene.delegate = self
            return scene
        }()

        func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval, forScene scene: SKScene) {
        }
    }

    // PlayerControlComponent.swift

    import Foundation

    enum PlayerDirection {
        case None, Left, Right, Down, Up
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're approaching your problem from the wrong angle.  It looks like what you want is to be able to access `playerDirection` from the `keyDown()` function in `GameScene`.  Instead of attempting to make `playerDirection` a property of the `SKSceneDelegate` protocol, you should probably be checking to see if the `delegate` property in `GameScene` is a `Game` and, if it is, casting `delegate` to `Game` so that the `playerDirection` property becomes available to you.

You can do that very easily with an `if let` and the `as?` operator like this:

```
override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    if let game = delegate as? Game {
        switch (theEvent.keyCode) {
        case 123:
            game.playerDirection = .Left;
        case 124:
            game.playerDirection = .Right;
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

This is doubly nice because now you're also checking to make sure that `delegate` actually exists before using it. Forcibly unwrapping it, like you were doing before, could cause a runtime exception if `delegate` isn't set when before that function is called.